# System Testing tool for Ubuntu

Tags: system, hardware-test

I want to test my hardware function and find errors.

Is there any System Testing tool available for Ubuntu ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### [Phoronix Test suite](https://github.com/phoronix-test-suite/phoronix-test-suite)

You can use **Phoronix Test suite**. It is best testing Utility for Linux Systems.

It is having a Dash icon. But runs in terminal. Takes few hours to run a comprehensive test. Finally gives a report.

[image: Install via the software center]

Or:

```
sudo apt install phoronix-test-suite
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Is there a standalone LiveCD version of this?

Answer (score 18):

Try

**System Testing**

System Testing, can test your system and submit results to the Ubuntu Friendly project.

You have to manually participate for the test.

To install, just click [**System Testing** [image: Install comixcursors-lefthanded]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/checkbox-qt/)

Can also install with :

```
sudo apt-get install checkbox-gui
```

[image]

Comment: This [Launchpad Page](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu-friendly), will give some information.

Comment: Is there a GTK version?

Comment: this doesn't exist.  probably now `checkbox-converged` and available under Applications -> Other -> Checkbox

Comment: I am a bit confused... This seems to be a suite to test compatibility with ubuntu, rather than if the hardware is working OK (no problems with RAM memory, few bad blocks). Does it do both? How do I choose the hardware tests?

Comment: @josinalvo Checkbox is a test runner for Ubuntu. It aims to provide a common framework to run all types of tests, from hardware tests, to command line tests, unit tests or desktop tests. For all the test that you can do see [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Checkbox).

Comment: Is there a CPU load test included?

Comment: Not present anymore at least on 18.04. [_CheckboxNG replaces Checkbox, where applicable_](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/checkbox_ng.1.html)?

Answer (score 8):

#### [hw-probe](https://snapcraft.io/hw-probe)

Try hw-probe tool on your host [with a Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/linuxhw/hw-probe/) or

```
sudo snap install hw-probe
```

The probe includes outputs of several Linux diagnostics tools (smartctl, memtester, etc.), hardware listers (hwinfo, dmidecode, biosdecode, etc.) and system logs (Xorg.log, dmesg, etc.).

Probe example: https://linux-hardware.org/?probe=0b29192f95

[image: screenshot]

I'm the author of this project, so feel free to ask any questions in comments!