# Compatibility with 14.04

Tags: system-installation

Is there a program that will test a system for compatibility with 14.04?  I am unable to install Ubuntu in a couple of older systems, and cannot determine why.

Comment: Yes see http://askubuntu.com/questions/389084/system-testing-tool-for-ubuntu Works from the live dvd.

Comment: Compatibility with what? Architecture? Scripts? Programs?

Comment: "I am unable to install Ubuntu in a couple of older systems, and cannot determine why" Why not give us the specs of these machines and any errors you got? Someone here can probably help with that, make a new question though.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any application that does that, but you can check the Ubuntu 14.04 requirements at [this link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements).

When you are on the page, go to Ubuntu Desktop Edition and there you have the requirements. Also, keep in mind that Unity has these requirements:

1000 MHz (about 1 GHz, or Intel Celeron and better.) 
1024 MiB of RAM (1000 MB, or 1 GB, or 1 GiB.)
3D Acceleration Capable graphics card with at least 256 MB of "GPU RAM" or just 256 MB, you know.

And to test if the hardware works, go on your Ubuntu Live Media and select "Try Ubuntu". If "Try Ubuntu" and "Install Ubuntu" isn't there, there is a problem with the Live Ubuntu Media and you may need to reinstall Ubuntu on the media.