# How to run a System Testing on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, hardware, hardware-test

I would like to verify if Ubuntu was properly installed and if all the drivers was correctly installed on my hardware. I would like to run tests, but don't know how. I have had problems installing Debian on this machine...  Now I've succeeded installing Ubuntu. But I need to really verify if everything is ok. Thank you in advance!

Comment: There aren't really any tests that you can run to "test" Ubuntu, however, you can learn how to check your file system with `fsck`, and review your disks SMART data using the `Disks` application, and learn how to review various log files like /var/log/syslog to determine if there are problems.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/389084/system-testing-tool-for-ubuntu