# Ubuntu constantly going to Emergency mode!

Tags: boot, 18.04, filesystem, crash, fdisk

Ubuntu 18.04 LST, went to the emergency mode the first time. Nothing works to exit the emergency mode (I tested many from the discussions here) except the following solution.

I fixed it using this guidance: https://medium.com/@nehamuthiyan/getting-out-of-the-emergency-mode-in-ubuntu-818180ce3940 which means that the home partition (separate from root) is corrupted. After fixing it, the ubuntu loads,  and works until 2-3 times shutdown.

But then, the same thing happens again. I first thought it is the root and home being full, so I reduced the volume, and now I am at 70% and 80% full disk.

I am near the end of a one of the most important projects of my life, and I cannot afford reinstallation at all. Plz help me figure this out and fix this. I cannot understand why this happens at all.

Comment: If you get repeated *unclean* file-systems, that is usually a symptom of a problem you're ignoring.  Once a year is the all you'd expect (*fluke power outage, UPS batteries need check* etc) any more than that is a *symptom* screaming for your attention - so explore & find out the cause.  Check RAM, check disk health (SMART), check PSU is reliable, check power itself (UPS issues? etc) ... ie. check your hardware & other likely causes  (software config could cause it too, but you should already be aware of those reasons so suggest looking at hardware)

Comment: +1 sounds much like hardware failure. If you have a spinning HDD, I'd say this is the most likely cause of failure, but RAM and PSU can also fail. You could start by stating how old the different parts in your system are. Also, no matter how much pressure you have by a project, you should consider a plan to replace the parts needed, and not continue on faulty hardware - this will only make things worse in the end.

Comment: My system is a laptop. Do you know good software to check what you mentioned before I contact the guarantee?

Comment: I just installed SMART with GSmartControl. Anything else?

Comment: Have a look [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/389084/system-testing-tool-for-ubuntu).

Comment: RAM test and Smart disk check return no errors. The laptop battery is functional and there seems to be no problem with the power as far as the power settings of the laptop show. When the system loads, there is also no noticeable problem either.  What else should I check and how?

Comment: Is your computer becoming extremely hot during operation from heavy CPU usage? This can also lead to shutdown in some cases.

Comment: If I perform a RAM-test; I let it run *overnight* at minimum, but if it's a machine I want to *trust* I tend to let it run for days  (ie. not just a single cycle, but many). I'd perform SMART tests from *live* media and not and installed system (like most testing); you can look up https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Smartmontools but GUI tools exist too. The best way I find to detect issues is regularly monitor & it's the changes that highlight issues (ie. compare with last months test, month before that etc). Checking hardware is done with tools, not software (eg. multi-meter, eyes etc)

Comment: Another finding, after a successful, when the system works for a few hours, some applications are not loaded anymore. For example, now after 2 hours, I am unable to start Gimp.